# How to add a minute in Python to Hive timestamp format

Tags: python, date

I wanted to add a minute to the date which is in the Hive timestamp format of 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6' using Python

Example:1) 2015-01-15 08:59:16 date after adding a minute should become  2015-01-15 09:00:16
2)

For this, I got the minute part from the date and added 1 to it with a modulo 60:
str((int(csvRowArray[1][10:12])+ 1)%60)

Here csvRowArray[1] is the date in string format.

The problem comes when the minute is 59, although it resets the minute part to 0, the hour part doesn't increase. This should also work when the hour is 23:59 and we add a minute, the date should change.Or if the date is at the end of the month and the hour is 23:59 then even the month should change!

Is there a function in Python to read the date in Hive timestamp format and add a minute to it?

Comment: the format includes microseconds while your examples do not. Is it intentional?

Comment: This one did not have microseconds. Although the next set might very well have it. If the data does not have microseconds then I cannot use the %f for all inputs right? I will manually need to add %f to the script for data that will have microseconds..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will help if you can convert the object into `DateTime` instances as that will allow you to manipulate the time directly using `timedelta`. Taking your example of '2015-01-15 08:59:16'

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
a='2015-01-15 08:59:16'
dt_obj = dt.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
dt_with_one_more_min = dt_obj + timedelta(minutes=1)
print('original time = {}'.format(dt_obj))
print('new time = {}'.format(dt_with_one_more_min))
```

This will give the following result:

```
original time = 2015-01-15 08:59:16
new time = 2015-01-15 09:00:16
```

My example is with minutes, but you can try other modifications too with `timedelta` and it will work.

Comment: to support microseconds, `%f` format could be used.